# What will be $\mu \left (f (\partial \left ([0,1]^k \right ) \right )\ $?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, smooth-functions

> Let $f : [0,1]^k \longrightarrow [0,1]^k$ be an one to one and onto $C^1$-map. We know that the Lebesgue measure of $\partial \left ( [0,1]^k \right )$ is zero. Can we conclude that the Lebesgue measure of $f \left ( \partial \left ([0,1]^k \right ) \right )$ is also zero?

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes it is $0$. one-to-one and onto are irrelevant in this situation, we only need the fact that $f$ is $C^1$ (by this I assume you mean there's an extension of $f$ to a $C^1$ map defined on an open set containing $[0,1]^k$). Since $f$ is $C^1$ and $[0,1]^k$ is compact, it is Lipschitz (by mean-value inequality and compactness). And it is a standard fact that locally Lipschitz maps send measure zero sets to measure zero sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, any Lispchitz function maps sets of measure $0$ to sets of measure $0$. And any $C^{1}$ map on $[0,1]^{k}$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: Why does every Lipschitz function send measure $0$ set to a measure $0$ set?

Comment: @Anacardium That is quite standard. Basically the idea is this: If $E$ has measure $0$ then we can cover $E$ by a sequence of rectangles with total area less than $\epsilon$. Lipschitz property impleis that the total area of the images of these rectangles is also small and $f(E)$ is covered by these images.